# 1D Convection equation C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ and currently I am trying to recode Professor Barbas's lectures on "12 Steps to Navier Stokes" but in C++ instead of Python. I attempted Step 1 and I am having some problems, below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Start of C++

    int nx = 41;
    double dx = double(2) /(nx-1);
    int nt = 25;
    double dt  = 0.025;
    int c = 1;
    double u[nx][nt];
    double un[nx][nt];    
    //Initial Condition.  Step function

    for (int i = 1; i <= nx-1; i++){
        if(i*dx >= 0.5 && i*dx <=1){
            u[i][0] = 2;
        }else{
            u[i][0] = 1;
        }
        cout << u[i][0] << endl;
    }

    //Finite Difference Loop 

    for (int it = 1; it<= nt-1; it++){
        for (int k = 0; k<= nx-1; k++){
            un[k][it-1] = u[k][it-1];   
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++){
            u[i][it+1] = u[i][it] - c*dt/dx*(un[i][it-1]-un[i-1][it-1]);

        }
    }


    //Advancing u[space][time] in time 
    //so collection of u[space][time++]
    // i.e u[s][t]

    for (int t = 1; t<= nt-1; t++){
        for (int s = 0; s<=nx-1; s++){
            cout << u[s][0] << endl;
            //This is not correct.  

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to plot U as it advances in time.  So I will have U[i][time = 0] for 1 graph, then U[i][time = 1] for another graph and so on. Now, how do I gets these arrays out of the U[i][it].  In my last for loop, what I tried to "cout" is not correct, because it will "cout" the entire 41 x 20 elements.  What should happen is to have a 41 elements array for 1 instant in time, then if I want, I can change to get the next block of 41 elements.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: `nt` and `nx` must be constant for the declarations of `double u[nx][nt];` and `double un[nx][nt];` to be portable. Some compilers (gcc) offer extensions to allow non-const dimensions but this is not supported by standard c++.

Comment: [Step 1](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/barbagroup/CFDPython/blob/master/lessons/01_Step_1.ipynb) from [CFDPython](https://github.com/barbagroup/CFDPython)

Comment: Can't tell exactly what your question is...  other than making your size vars const it should run.  if you want to break up the output from the arrays then put a simple statement between the for loops.  Like this:  `for (int t = 1; t<= nt-1; t++)
 {
  cout<<"\n  "<<endl;
        for (int s = 0; s<=nx-1; s++)
  {
            cout << u[s][0] << endl;
            //This is not correct.  

        }
    }`